# iOS 7 - UITableViewController big data source - strategy advice?

Tags: ios, json, cocoa-touch, uitableview

Xcode: 5.0.2
iOS: 7.0.x

I have a secondary view that is conditionally shown when a user logs in to my app. This secondary view shows a list of items that a user must choose one of as a "default" value for the lifetime of their authenticated session. This secondary view is going to be seen only once by the large majority of my users.

The list of items are returned in JSON from a web service and can be anywhere from 1 item to 1000 items. If one is returned, the secondary view won't even show.

The json will be structured with two elements again each item, and `id` and an `itemName`. I've estimated a few hundred kb download for a worst case scenario - and its a one time download. Perhaps a searchable API rather than a data-dump would be better practice?

Once the results are return they will be processed into two `NSArray`. An `NSArray` of `NSDictionary` for me to retrieve an `id` once selected and an `NSArray` of `NSString` containing `itemName` - used for populating `UITableView` and performing the keyword search against;

```
For retrieving ID reference:
[ { id: 0, itemName: "one" }, { id: 1 itemName: "two" } ]

For populating the UITableView data source
[ "one", "two" ]
```

Now I need this data in my `UITableView`. As this is a one-time operation (changeable later, but the users typically will not be changing this regularly) I was planning on adding the entire array into the `UITableView`.

Typically, what is the max size that you should put into the table view? Will this cause me some serious memory issues? How will the keyword search fair when searching against 100's - 1000.

I'm also looking at perhaps updating the UI to follow that very closely of the Contacts app (`UILocalizedIndexedCollation`?) so again it will have an impact on this.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having a JSON, a corresponding Foundation representation will consume *roughly* 5 times more RAM than the length in bytes.

So, for example if your JSON is 300 Kbyte (UTF-8), then NSJSONSerialization will create a Foundation hierarchy which may consume 1.5 MByte RAM.

This amount fits nicely into RAM.

If, and only if you don't want to *persist* the JSON representation or a corresponding Model, and don't want to utilize Core Data for other reasons (e.g. editing, undo, rollbacks, etc.), I would strongly argument *against* using Core Data: since your data is still "small" in the worst case, there's no need to utilize Core Data in the assumption it would safe you memory.

Core Data isn't cheap either, memory wise. In your case, using Core Data would actually cause your App to consume *much more* RAM, because of SQLite's buffers and caches, Core Data buffers and caches and internal structures. In practice and given your scenario with 1000 objects, a Core Data /SQLite approach would consume roughly 4 Mbyte. This is about 3 times more than your JSON representation. On the other hand, Core Data may not consume much more RAM when your number of elements increase tremendously and when there is also memory pressure.

Comment: Thank you for this, it is an interesting point. The data will not persist, as a user can only ever select one item from 1000 to save as a default - once the row is selected i will then store that single item on disk and that will be the only persistence. I feel maybe this is actually more efficient and simpler to implement. As a side note, I have just ran off a full demo file and with the current max of 800 items its 85kb

Comment: I tested again with 3,000+ elements in the json file and works without a minor hiccup. Perfect, thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

I will also strongly recommended to you `CoreData` approach with `UIFetchedResultController`. This is solution crafted for your problem. While you're downloading the data from the web, `FetchedResultController` will display empty table view, and when download is complete or "enough" you might display the data without blocking user interface.

What's more, if you want to display a huge database at once, the controller manage to fetched more data "by itself" when user scroll down.

Of course `UILocalizedIndexedCollation` is also supported here.

Comment: Thanks for the answer here. As I'm only using this data set once, is it worth storing using CoreData? When a user comes to change their item if they wanted to do, chances are it would need to be re-downloaded anyway as they would be looking for an item that did not previously exist. 

I see this as a "disposable" data set you see, and want to make sure its efficient longterm and shorterm - and avoid doing any complicated operations like re-syncing the CoreData etc for such a minimally used task.

Comment: You have to store it somewhere anyway. CoreData is best place, because with `NSPredicate` you can change and load whatever you want. You don't have really more alternative here (also pure sqlite file will do). The re-syncing operation is handling by `UIManagedDocument` :)

Comment: I'm still new to iOS development but the NSPredicate class looks ideal for what I want. Time to google for some tutorials on how to set this up..! If you know of any good learning resources please let me know. Many thanks for you help!

Comment: The best tutorial with sample code came from CS193p lecture. You can download example code from here: http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/cgi-bin/drupal/node/389 And full lecture you can find in iTunes U. Enjoy!